# Dir > txt cmd from WiFi Attached Storage

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some movie files stored on a FileFub Plus which is a wifi hub with a sd card – which I can access over my LAN. Once I connect to the FHP’s wifi (entering password etc)  I can access the files through my Win7 File Manager using the address \\10.10.10.254.

What I want to be able to do is run a cmd batch file to output all the file names to a txt file on my PC’s hard drive.

Normally, it w/b easy to use a cmd such as, (which FYI is the cmd I use to output my MyCloud movie files),

```
dir \\192.168.1.111\moviez /s > c:\”MyCloud_Movies.txt”
```

So I tried the following;

```
dir \\10.10.10.254\SDCard_Volume1\Movies /s > c:\”FileHub Plus Movies.txt”
```

FYI – the ‘root’ (share) directory of the FHP is labeled SDCard_Volume1 and then the movies are in a sub dir called Movies.

Also FYI my connection to the FHP, using File Manager, does not display a drive letter.

When I run the above cmd it doesn’t output the file names to the txt file – and I get an error “Logon failure; unknown user or bad password” (even though I have the \\10.10.10.254 location already open in File Manager on my notebook)…

So I guess my first questions are what am I doing wrong and how would I input the password so I can run this batch fle to create a list of my movies on the FHP…?

Comment: By File Manager do you mean Windows Explorer?

Comment: I doubt the system will allow you to create a file in the root of the system drive `C:`. I experience no problem with `dir \\192.168.0.2\share\...` to a cabled network attached storage. Though, username and password requirement may depend on your share settings.

Comment: the smart quotes in `”FileHub Plus Movies.txt”` are not supported by cmd as well as any other shells to surround strings

Comment: replace your smart quotes as well as their positions with double quotes. So simply copy this as is and try: `dir /s /b \\10.10.10.254\SDCard_Volume1\Movies > "c:\FileHub Plus Movies.txt"`

Comment: Really appreciate all the comments - I'm traveling (to a nice hot sunny place this week !!) so I'll try the suggestions next week when I'm back home ... (to the cold and snow  ;-(

Comment: Tried your idea Gerhard - no go...
Ran the bat from the Movies directory and from a cmd line on the Desktop, but got " A req'd privilege is not held by the client" ...
Maybe because of the security privileges on the Movies directory I tried to change (using Props) to Full Control but then got msg,
Error Applying Security - an error occurred while applying security information to \\10.10.10.254\SDCard_Volume1\Movies Access is Denied"
FYI a) this Win7 Laptop is on a Domain, b) Win File Explorer has full control of the FHP files - ie. can delete, rename, them etc)...
Welcome more advice.

Comment: Tried using a Win10 notebook (that was NOt on a domain) connected to the FHP and also no go with the bat file - got an error = "CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories."

Comment: Progress - PowerShell seems to the solution.  From within PS, running in cmd window on PC I can run   \\10.10.10.254\SDCard_Volume1\Movies> dir > c:Test\\test.txt   and I get a listing of the files...  Now need to figure out how to make the PS cmd run from a bat file...